# ambari cluster + get status of component/services by tool / python script

Tags: python, hadoop, ambari

we have few Hadoop machines , and we use the API in our bash script to get the status of the components or services in the Hadoop cluster from Ambari API

I searched in google but without help ,

but I am almost sure that somewhere there is a tool or python script that already exists  , that can capture the component status or services status in the cluster and maybe some other useful options,

I will appreciate to get help about this tool / script

example:

one of our tasks is to get the status of all components/services in the cluster ( prefer not to use each individual API for each component , we prefer one API that will show the status of all the components in the cluster )

Comment: It must be multiple requests. All services. All components for a service... Thats just how the API is written https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/components-component.md

Comment: in that case - do you know about tools /script that can do the things easily ? , I mean tools that include all API combination to give the requested results

Comment: Asking for tools and off site resources is off topic for Stackoverflow, sorry. Plenty of tools called "Ambari shell" exist on github

Answer (score 1):

You can get the state - STARTED/STOPPED by using the below API Calls

For services

```
curl -u {ambari-username}:{ambari-password} -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://{ambari-host}:{ambari-port}/api/v1/clusters/{clustername}/services/{service-name}?fields=Serv...
```

For components

```
curl -u {ambari-username}:{ambari-password} -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://{ambari-host}:{ambari-port}/api/v1/clusters/{clustername}/components/{component-name}?fields=...
```

To get complete status info about service

```
curl -u {ambari-username}:{ambari-password} -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://{ambari-host}:{ambari-port}/api/v1/clusters/{clustername}/services/{service-name}
```

To get complete status info about component

```
curl -u {ambari-username}:{ambari-password} -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://{ambari-host}:{ambari-port}/api/v1/clusters/{clustername}/components/{component-name}
```

Replace the place holders like {ambari-username} , {ambari-password}, {ambari-host} , {ambari-port},{clustername} etc with your respective values

refer: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/how-to-capture-all-ambari-services-components-status-by-API/m-p/179704/highlight/true#M141950